# robotis.launch trouble finding AX 12 dynamixel motors

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello...

I am trying to run pi_tracker.. But,when I use "roslaunch pi_tracker robotis.launch" I encounter none of the motors are detected..

I have tried to detected the motors using the dynamixel_motor package and can successfully detect and identify motors.

Currently I am connecting 3 motors(id 1, 6, 7). The usb2dynamixel is currently set to TTL..

How could this problem solved ?

Thank you...

Installed: ubuntu 11.10 x32 electric pi_tracker pyserial

dynamixel_motors:

> [INFO] [WallTime: 1363075666.690905] Pinging motor IDs 1 through 25...
> [INFO] [WallTime: 1363075667.065507] Found motors with IDs: [1, 6, 7].
> [INFO] [WallTime: 1363075667.225608] There are 3 AX-12+ servos connected
> [INFO] [WallTime: 1363075667.226162] Dynamixel Manager on port /dev/ttyUSB0
> initialized

pi_tracker:

> 

RuntimeError: lib_robotis: Error encountered. Could not find ID (1) on bus (/dev/ttyUSB0), or USB2Dynamixel 3-way switch in wrong position.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57879/robotis.launch-trouble-finding-ax-12-dynamixel-motors/) by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Rizqa,

If you are using the current version of the robotis package [from here](http://code.google.com/p/gt-ros-pkg/source/browse/ repo=hrl#git%2Fhrl_hardware_drivers%2Frobotis), then it appears that it is no longer reading ROS parameters to set the baudrate and port.  The defaults are 57600 for baudrate and /dev/ttyUSB0 for the port.  You probably need to change the baudrate to 1000000 which you can do by editing the lib_robotis.py file:

```
$ roscd robotis/src/robotis
```

Then edit the file lib_robotis.py and change the baud rate to 1000000.  This worked for me.

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on 2013-03-12**:
Thanks.. it works fine.. :)